# Receber um numero através de uma Stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, stored-procedures

Tenho um objeto que tem propriedades do vários tipos e um deles é um List <int?>, entretanto ao executar uma procedure ele me retorna apenas um numero, funciona se eu tirar a lista e deixar apenas int?, so que eu preciso realmente de um alista pois será acrescido elementos desta Lista. o erro que esta dando é:

> Error parsing column 28 (Imoid=22 - Int32)

propriedade da Classe: `public List< int?> ImoId { get; set; }`
Chamada a Sprocedure:

```
var bookings = db.Query<BookingEntity>("Sp_061_Int_Plat_Booking01", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 600);
return bookings;
```

Como eu faço para receber um inteiro apenas nesta propriedade?

Usando Imapper

Comment: Como você configurou seu mapper para receber sua classe BookingEntity?

Comment: Sim, mas a propriedade é uma List de int, e o que vem da procedure é apenas um int. Na verdade ele foi modificado para ser um List, antes era um int e funconava normal, agora foi criado uma tabela para isto. e o cliente nao quer alterar o model.